# In Python how can I create a method in a class that assigns values to attributes

Tags: python, class, methods, instantiation, init

I want a method to run that assigns values to an object rather than declaring them in the parentheses. I have the following code that does not work. I'm open to all solutions including those that include methods that are contained in the constuctor.

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name): 
        self.name = name
        
    #gather player detail method

    def player_details():
        return input('Name: ')

player1 = Player.player_details()
#I want the following line of code to output whatever the player name was entered as
print (player1.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

## TRY this code using getter setter

class Player:
def **init**(self,name=""):
self.name = name

## getter method

def get_player_details(self):
return self.name

## setter method

def set_player_details(self, x):
self.name = x

player1 = Player()

## setting the age using setter

input_detail = input("Enter player name : ")

#set input as a player detail
player1.set_player_details(input_detail)

## retrieving age using getter

print(player1.get_player_details())

print(player1.name)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can just assign like a normal property:

```
def player_details(self):
    self.name = input('Name: ')
```

Or you can get an argument too:

```
def player_details(self, newName):
    self.name = newName
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for? You seem to have accidentally created your method as a 'static method' i.e. one which does not access the attributes of the class. You can change that by adding 'self' as an argument.

```
class Player:
        def __init__(self, name): 
            self.name = name
            
        #gather player detail method
    
        def player_details(self):
            self.name = input('Name: ')
    
player1 = Player.player_details()
# I want the following line of code to output whatever the player name was entered as
print (player1.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this achieved what I wanted, thank you.

```
class Player:
        def __init__(self, name =""): 
            self.name = input('Name: ')
            
    
#creating an instance of the Player class prompts the user to input name
#say I input "Jo"
player1 = Player()

#prints out "Jo"
print (player1.name)
```